# How many primes of $ap+b$ with $(a,b)=1$ and $p$ be any primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

There is a famous **Dirichlet's result**, which says: There are infinitely many primes of form $an+b$, where $(a,b)=1$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Denote the set of all primes by $\mathbb{P}$.**
Given two coprime numbers $a$, $b$, how many primes of form $ap+b$, where $p\in\mathbb{P}$? 
For example, how many primes of form $2p+1$, where $p\in\mathbb{P}$?

More generally, for a given irreducible primitive polynomial $f(x)$, is $\{f(p)~|~p\in\mathbb{P}\}\cap\mathbb{P}$ a finite set? Did somebody study this problem?

I also need to cite this **Dirichlet's result**. Could anyone tell me from which book or article I can cite this theorem?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are fixed integers and you're iterating over the prime numbers for $p$, right?

Comment: Yes. @Stefan4024

Comment: You could take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful. @Mastrem

Answer (score 1):

No univariate polynomial with integer coefficients and degree greater than $1$ is known to produce infinite many primes.

But many such polynomials , as $x^2+1$ are conjectured to produce infinite many primes.

For more details, see here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful. @Peter